# Pioneer3-AT Rviz/urdf model

Tags: simulation, rviz, robot-model, pioneer, p3at

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!

I am running a SLAM simulation using a Pioneer3-AT and it would be usefull if I had the pioneer's model on Rviz. That is, is there a way or a place where I can get a model of the P3-AT running on Rviz (urdf?) ? My objective is to have the real pioneer working on real world and a "picture" of him running on Rviz (in the same position as my "\base_link").

I know there is p2os_urdf, but the model it gives is not exactly the one I want. Is there an easy way to edit this model into the one I want?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64438/pioneer3-at-rviz/urdf-model/) by [Mendelson](https://answers.ros.org/users/3146/mendelson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2013-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Check here](http://ros.org/wiki/p2os-vanderbilt) for p2os_urdf. It has recently been updated to include the Pioneer3-AT URDF.

```
roslaunch p2os_urdf pioneer3at_urdf.launch
```

---

Also, when you say "not exactly the model you want," what do you mean?

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2013-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) on 2014-10-18**:
can we have the same for fuerte